# Salesforce1 Summer’15 release: Salesforce1 Actions don't appear on action bar/action menu after overriding the predefined actions

Tags: salesforce1-app

According to the Summer’15 release, you can override the predefined actions within Actions in the Salesforce1 Actions Bar.
[image: Screen from Summer’15 Release Note: Customize Actions in the Salesforce1 Action Bar]

Once I made the changes that were needed, after overriding the predefined actions, the actions that I’ve added and the predefined actions available previously are not showing in the Salesforce1 Action Bar/Action Menu.

It’s important to address that:
I am not adding custom actions.  These are basic quick actions, productivity actions, and/or standard/default actions.

2) Even though it’s not the focus of this issue, just to clarify that both Chatter and Actions in the Publisher are enabled.

3) I have doubled checked the Global Actions, Page Layout Assignment and of course, refreshed the screen

4) I’ve done a simulation in my browser using https://.salesforce.com/one/one.app in a Mac computer and running the app in my Android phone.  Getting the same results on both systems.

[image: Contact Layout(example)]

Just for clarification: I am not creating a new action either.  I'm only using the actions already provided by Salesforce

For example, the actions highlighted are the ones missing and below are the actions currently available on the Salesforce1 preview for my Contact Object (example):

[image: Current Actions available]

What should I do to make available all the actions highlighted above after completing the overriding process in the Salesforce1 app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application needs refreshed before these kinds of changes will apply. Since you're using an emulator, they may not show up immediately. Some of them may also be contextual. I've had the same experience in the actual application where I needed to clear the log out, shut down the app, clear it's cache, and then restart and log-in before the changes would take hold.

Comment: Did you try clearing any caches you may have for your browser or emulator?

Comment: you're right! I've noticed that I need to clear my browser cache almost every time I make changes while using Chrome. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Community etiquette is to help others by marking your question as solved through checking the answer that resolved your issue. If you don't, it leaves the impression to anyone who searches the topic later that your question wasn't answered to your satisfaction. Once you have sufficient reputation, you can also upvote posts and answers.